# Titanium Alloy - TabGroup and Toolbar simultaneously

Tags: android, ios, titanium-alloy

I'm using Appcelerator's Titanium Alloy to work on an app that features both a tab-group on the bottom of the screen and a toolbar on the top of the screen. These both will appear after login, and won't change until logged out. I have been able to create both the tab-group and the toolbar, but am having trouble having them both on the screen.

The toolbar that I'm going for is something similar to this: 
[How to create a header bar with buttons in Titanium JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945047/how-to-create-a-header-bar-with-buttons-in-titanium-js?rq=1)

Just a guess, but I think the views of the tab-group and the toolbar are getting overlapped with one another. As such, I'm only able to see one at a time, always the one I set second (i.e. it is on top of the other bar).

Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Edit:

I've looked into adjusting the `leftNavButton` and `rightNavButton` properties, but to use this method would require each individual tab to be adjusted, instead of the entire tab group. I'd like to find a way to add these buttons universally, as the top and bottom bars do not change with different views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rightNavButtons and leftNavButtons properties of the windows to add buttons to the navigationBar that is showing at the top of the screen in a tabgroup.

Comment: I've looked into this previously. The `leftNavButton` and `rightNavButton` properties belong to the `Window`. The Tab Group does not have its own Window, as the individual Tab's each have a Window. I was trying to find a way to set it up universally within the app, instead of having to re-code within each individual tab. Is this something that is possible?

Comment: That's not possible, but you could add the RightNavButton and LeftNavButton elements in a separate view and use Require to include that in all the window views.

Comment: Ok good to know. I got it to work using what you mentioned initially, just not in the way that I intended, but still functional, so thank you for the help!